# C++ write new line to text document and read it by index

Tags: c++

I'm new with C++
so I'm trying figure out with text document how to use it

first thing is how to write each random value to the new line in text document? Something is wrong with my code:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int a;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i(0); i < 10; i++)
    {
        a = rand() % 1000 + 1;// diapason

        cout << "ID: " << i << " Random: " << a << endl;

        std::ofstream outfile("test.txt");

        outfile << a << std::endl;

        outfile.close();

    }


    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file ***before*** the loop. Each time through the loop you open the same file, removing the contents of the file that were written on the previous iteration of the loop.

As far as reading the file, there is nothing more than doing just that, very similar to how the file gets written. Open a file, and read it one line at a time, using `std::getline()`, until you read the line that you are looking for. That is, if you want the 2nd line in the file, iterate the loop that reads the file two times. The last `std::getline()` call will give you the line.

Comment: Sam Varshavchik@ hi, and don't close it?

Comment: Why, yes. Why would you want to close it, before you finish writing everything to the file?

Comment: Open a file, read it one line at a time. Do you  know how to keep track of which line # you've just read from the file? Of course you do. `int line_number=0;`, and in the loop that reads each line of the file, "++line_number". Now, `line_number` is the current line that was just read from the file. When it reaches the index you're looking for, you're done.